# Syntax for matplotlib parameters on a pandas hist

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html), the pandas hist method to create a dataframe can take a parameter `ax` to presumably pass some kind plotting parameters to the `ax` object. What I want to know is how I pass these parameters.  Here is some code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
pd.DataFrame.hist(df,column='col1', ax={ylim(-1000,1000), set_title('new title')})
```

The above code seeks to modify the y-axis limits and title using the `ax` parameter, but I'm not sure of the syntax to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the *output* of `hist()` that creates a Matplotlib `Axes` object. 
 From the [`plot()` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

> **Returns: axes** : *matplotlib.AxesSubplot or np.array of them*

You can use that returned to make adjustments.

```
ax = df.col1.hist()
ax.set_title('new_title')
ax.set_ylim([-1000,1000])
```

The `ax` argument inside `plot()` (and variants like `hist()`) is used to plot on a predefined Axes element.  For example, you can use `ax` from one plot to overlay another plot on the same surface:

```
ax = df.col1.hist()
df.col2.hist(ax=ax)
```

[image: overlay plot]

Note: I updated your syntax a bit.  Call `hist()` as a method on the data frame itself.

**UPDATE**
Alternately, you can pass keywords directly, but in that case you (a) need to call `plot.hist()` instead of just `hist()`, and (b) the keywords are passed either as `kwargs` or directly in line.  For example:

```
kwargs ={"color":"green"}
# either kwargs dict or named keyword arg work here
df.col1.plot.hist(ylim=(5,10), **kwargs)
```

Comment: The docs make it seem like you can do this directly from the call to `hist`, but I still can't figure out that approach.  Thanks for you solution.

Comment: You can do this too.  I think you need `plot.hist()` though, then you can just pass keywords directly to Matplotlib's method, like `df.col1.plot.hist(ylim=(5,10))`.  I'll add an example.

Comment: The direct way is also referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38433359/2799941).